# How to create a searchable textblock in windows8

Tags: windows-8, controls

I want to create a searchable textblock which user can search their desired content, I've found a WPF sample here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWPFSearchAndHighlightText-3b5e207a,
but some of the method isn't available in winrt api, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound a little weak, but you could easily accomplish this in HTML. That's no reason to move away from XAML. There is nothing stopping you from writing the solution as an embedded HTML/JavaScript page using a WebView and projecting the result as a WebViewBrush. The user won't know any different and your problem is resolved.

Comment: Could you please provide more details?